# Parted not properly auto aligning sectors for usb drive

Tags: filesystems, partition, parted

I am trying to partition a usb 3 drive but for some reason parted can't properly set the start sector. The drive is identical to multiple other sata drives, the only difference is that it's inside a usb 3 enclosure with 2 port hub integrated. I wouldn't have though it would matter.

Here are the steps I always used before:

```
sudo parted /dev/sd?
mklabel gpt
mkpart primary 0% 100%
quit
```

Here is fdisk -l output of the last 2 drives:

```
Disk /dev/sdk: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DB93D173-858A-475C-81CD-DB616E91C110

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdk1   2048 15628053134 15628051087  7.3T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdl: 7.3 TiB, 8001563221504 bytes, 15628053167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B3791850-76F8-4CE2-B1CC-DF40886292CE

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdl1  65535 15628000379 15627934845  7.3T Linux filesystem

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Second drive is the problematic one.

Performance really seems to take a big hit as formatting to ext4 takes a long time (never waited to finish) where normally it would only take seconds. Why is this happening? How can I get proper alignment?

The only other difference I can think of is that it was originally formatted as ntfs with some un-partitioned space. I also ran this command to clear any leftover partitions: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdl bs=512 count=10000` with no luck.

Using optimal alignment doesnt work either:

```
sudo parted -a optimal /dev/sdl mkpart primary 0% 100%


Warning: You requested a partition from 0.00B to 8002GB (sectors 0..15628053166).
The closest location we can manage is 17.4kB to 1048kB (sectors 34..2047).
Is this still acceptable to you?
```

Answer (score 2):

The optimal I/O size of the second drive is much larger than that of the first one; that is probably what is causing the issue. [This article from 2013](http://rainbow.chard.org/2013/01/30/how-to-align-partitions-for-best-performance-using-parted/) suggests to manually align partitions starting at (Optimal I/O + Alignment Offset) / Physical Block Size = starting slice, and reading how parted words nowadays it seems like this was rolled in to how parted works by default. Now, performing that math on your parameters returns 8191.875 as the starting slice, which is probably not a valid sector address.

It seems most likely to me that your USB enclosure is misrepresenting the optimal I/O of the drive. I would try manually specifying the starting sector as 2048, matching the first drive, when you make the partition try using `mkpart primary 2048s 100%`. That should work around it.

If you have the opportunity you can check this beforehand by plugging the drive into a computer without the USB enclosure and then checking `/sys/block/[drive]/queue/optimal_io_size` if it exists. If it doesn't match, the USB enclosure is probably misreporting the drive's capabilities.

Comment: I did try "mkpart primary 2048s 100%" but same warnings still. Will try to break into the case next.

Comment: There's nothing for you to check by connecting the drive directly to a SATA port. minimum/optimal_io_size is set from minimum/optimal transfer length in the block limits VPD. minimum/optimal transfer length isn't even a thing in ATA standard so technically there's nothing wrong for a UAS/USB-SATA bridge to report a value like 65535 (it might originate from the maximum length of a certain SCSI or ATA write command can cover).

Comment: When you connect the drive to a SATA port, the job ("faking" the block limit VPD) goes to libata, which does not report an optimial i/o length (but only a minimum which is essentially physical block size divided by logical block size)

Comment: Relevant code in the kernel: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12/source/drivers/ata/libata-scsi.c#L2370 http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12/source/drivers/scsi/sd.c#L2861 http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12/source/drivers/scsi/sd.c#L3096

Comment: Partitioning works fine in another USB dock so it is indeed an issue with USB adapter. After partitioning and formatting fdisk -l gives "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used." warning when used back in the original USB case.

Comment: In fairness, the term `optimal_io_size` is misleading if it's supposed to describe optimal alignment of read/write operations. No wonder some vendors get it wrong and report what may be the maximum block size the interface can receive without fragmentation. In the example, I guess the USB to SATA bridge has 32 MiB RAM and can use all but 512 bytes of it as buffer for data (32*1024^2-33553920=512).

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue in `fdisk` in util-linux. I reported to upstream quite sometime ago and it has been fixed:

https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/acb7651f8897ae73d0f45dd75bc87630001c61b9

So if you use fdisk in util-linux v2.27-rc1 or later *to create partitions*, you would not experience the problem.

I am not sure if `parted` has the same problem, if it does, it should probably introduce similar hack. (So file a bug report to upstream if you want to get it fixed: http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/parted/)

EDIT: Just notice that you are using GPT on both disks. IIRC `gdisk` does not suffer from this problem because it doesn't calculate alignment using the optimal i/o size, instead it statically defaults to 2048 and allows you to set it to any value range from 1 - 65536 (`x` -> `l`).

Comment: fdisk from util-linux 2.28.2 so it couldn't have been the problem in any case.

Comment: @DominicM what do you mean? Have you actually tried using fdisk to *(re)create* the partitions? I am not saying that it's a bug of `fdisk -l`. Have you misread? Note that `parted` has nothing to do with `fdisk` or `util-linux`.

Comment: I thought you said earlier not later. In any case it's not fdisk as parted gave the warnings too. It turns out that Seagates USB controller is simply not competently designed making it impossible to partition properly.

Comment: @DomonicM what warnings? I have no idea what you are talking about any more. FWIW I have UAS bridge that reports 65535 as optimal transfer length as well, partition aligning works fine with `fdisk` and `gdisk`. Seriously just give up `parted`, coz it sucks on every aspect and no longer have release cycle since 2014 (so it sucks even more unless you or your distro do a regular git build)

Comment: @DominicM the best solution is to zap the GPT (both the primary and backup) and the PMBR with `gdisk` (`x` -> `z` -> `y` -> `y`), and create new partition table and new partition(s) *with it* from scratch. You won't even be aware of the optimal transfer length thing anymore.

Comment: Read the original question, it clearly includes the parted warning. If you read the other answer and comments its an issue with the usb adapter as it works perfectly with another one. Parted may have issues too but it's not the only issue here.

Comment: @DominicM If you read my detailed comments on the other answer you'll know I've read it and that I know what's going on there with your adapters. As I have said repeatedly, I have an adapter myself that reports optimal transfer length as 65535 (hence optimal i/o size 33553920 bytes, 65535 blocks  * 512-byte per logical block).

Comment: @DominicM the warning you quoted in the end of your question isn't even relevant. What it tells is that it makes no sense to and you can't create a partition starts with LBA 0 (the first block of the disk), coz that's where the (P)MBR lies, and neither is LBA 1 - 33 is available coz that's where the primary GPT lies. So it can only *possibly* starts with LBA 34 (if you don't care about alignment). In other words, `parted` does not expect you to use `0%` as the start of a partition.

Comment: @DominicM if you see exactly the same warning (that you request a partition from sector 0 to sector blah blah blah) even if you explicitly stated 2048s as the start, then clearly parted is bugged to a greater extent than we expected since it's obviously ignoring your instruction.

Comment: If you knew what's going on you wouldn't say exact opposite -  "what warnings? I have no idea what you are talking about any more. ".

Comment: Yes parted seems to have issues. gdisk did not result in warning however ext4 formatting still took orders of magnitude longer so it's not the the only issue here. The real solution is to use proper USB adapter as I am doing now, no issues whatsoever with my USB dock.

Comment: @DominicM No, I said that because you were being ambiguous, since you also mentioned some other warning about corrupt GPT in a later comment (which I don't think is relevant either but probably caused by some other mishandling). So I was confused (or even annoyed) on which irrelevant warning (maybe yet another) you are bring in again. Anyway, suit yourself if you think I don't know what's going on here. No point for me to prove it to you (well, if you read the fdisk commit carefully you'll noticed it's proved anyway).

Comment: @DominicM well that's another story (long mkfs). It could be the the optimal transfer length causing it (because it is AF 512e drive), or it could be some other reason. The only way to find out is to hack the scsi disk driver so that it would ignore the value (consider it reported 0). I am not asking you to test it though, but it's the only fair test to see if the value is the problem. I would probably do that myself if I have such disk and experience same performance issue.